# how to return the four highest value in an array after matching them with a string in php

Tags: php, arrays

Please could anyone tell me how to get the four highest values from an array after matching them with a string. for example:

```
<?php 
$a = array(
 'b'=>'123hrtr',
 'c'=>'345kildd'
 'd'=>'nhr766'); 
  $new_string = 'wynh551234';
```

The idea here is to match the $new_string with values in the array and get the count of the number of characters that was matched and then with this count, display the value with the highest count, and if there are more than one value, display them(for example, if more than one value happens to have the highest count,display them).

Comment: The question isn't specific enough, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It isn't really clear what you want. In addition to reading How to Ask you should include an example of the type of output you're wanting to generate.

Comment: So, just iterate over the array, calculate the score and sort descending. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can loop through string just as it would be an array in php (if I am wrong, use substr() function).

So loop through array and loop through every string in that array, then try to find every character in the provided string (substr_count() function) and count matches. If you need to find more then 1 longest match, you need to save every best match in some array and clear it evrytime you find a better (longer) result (I actually skipped this so you have to do it on your own or sort the result array and pick the best results).

Edit:

...and you need to keep track of characters already matched for every string:

```
$resultsArray = array();
$alreadyMatched = array();
foreach($a as $key => $arrayString) {
    $length = strlen($arrayString);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $char = $arrayString[$i];// or something like substr($arrayString, $i, 1)
        If(!in_array($char, $alreadyMatched)) {
            $score += substr_count($new_string, $char);
            $alreadyMatched[] = $char;
        }
    }
    $resultsArray[$key] = $score;
    $alreadyMatched = array();
}
```

$resultsEdit now has the results for every string in the original array (under the same index as original array) so now you have to sort it and pick the highest value. Don't copy&paste the code, I am on my phone atm, so take it more like pseudocode. You should be able to get the general idea.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply,please, would you mind giving me a sample code on what your answer?

Comment: See edited answer. Note that I am not near PC atm so take it more like pseudo code than functional PHP code example